# Отправка email из приложения

Tags: java, android

Необходимо реализовать функцию отправки `email` по нажатию кнопки, не могу найти рабочий пример

Answer (score 6):

```
//EmailSending
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "example@gmail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ТЕМА");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Написать письмо..."));
```

Comment: это вызывает приложение через которое будет отправлено сообщение, а мне необходимо непосредственно из моего приложения отправка через `smtp`

Answer (score 2):

Создаем класс GMailSender для авторизации в gmail

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
private String user;
private String password;
private Session session;

static {
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
}

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,this);
}

protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
    try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
        Transport.send(message);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
    private byte[] data;
    private String type;

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        if (type == null)
            return "application/octet-stream";
        else
            return type;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");
    }
}
}
```

Создаем провайдер

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

public JSSEProvider() {
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
        public Void run() {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Отправка почты

```
                GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("почта", "пароль");
                sender.sendMail("тема письма",
                        тело письма,
                        "откуда (тот же адрес, что и почта)",
                        куда);
```

Вам понадобятся подключить три джарника.
[первый](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/mail.jar)
[второй](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/activation.jar)
[третий](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/additionnal.jar)

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь JavaMail https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Android

Вот здесь неплохой туториал - http://javapapers.com/android/android-email-app-with-gmail-smtp-using-javamail/

Comment: И правда, последний туториал очень интересный, с ним получилось реализовать отправку